# How can I get a programming job abroad with some experience but no formal computing qualifications?

Tags: job-search, work-experience, careers

I don't have a degree in computer engineering or related field however I have studied international politics at university. After I graduated and started working, I became interested in programming, quit my job and started learning programming. I have since made a few Android projects which I've shared on GitHub.

Now one and a half years has passed and I want to start my career abroad somewhere like Canada, Australia or in a European country.

How can I overcome the lack of experience and degree and still make this happen?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't start your career in your home country and look to immigrate later on?  Wherever you are, it seems very unlikely that you're authorized to work in Canada, Australia, and Europe at the same time.  It would be far more likely that some company would sponsor you if you had some relevant experience.  It would be terribly unlikely that a company would want to (or be able to) sponsor a visa for someone with no degree and no experience.

Comment: Have you considered further education? If so, do you have post-graduate certificates in your country? You already have a bachelor so you would qualify for post-graduate study and often these are significantly shorter to complete (6mo-1yr) and considered equivalent to a bachelor.

Comment: Aside from "get the experience" or "get a degree", I'm struggling to think of any other answer than "get lucky". I can't see any company hiring a unproven candidate with no relevant experience or education, especially if the candidate is international. Edit: from your profile you're Italian so working in the EU is less of a problem if you can somehow bridge the experience gap. If you are indeed Italian, consider adding that to your post as it's significantly easier to work internationally than if you were from India for instance.

Comment: A lot of comments here jumped to the conclusion you want to immigrate somewhere, but in your post, you only said you want to _work_ somewhere.  Which is it?  If you just want to work somewhere, depending on how old you are, you may be qualify for just a working-holiday visa.  Get the visa, go to that country, and follow Adel's advice underneath to sell yourself.

Answer (score 0):

But you just described in your post that you do have programming experience! Having a number of *real-world* projects, especially those that are well-received, is *exactly* what a smart employer would want to see.

The challenge for you will be selling yourself. You should aim more for the non-traditional job route - i.e network a lot and make real-life friends. Attend conferences and meet and greet. This is the best way to get in, not by the paper route.

However, when you have some more flexibility - do consider getting that certificate/degree. I think this helps with the big, more bureaucratic firms (startups and small firms are more open, generally, to programmers who might not have CS degrees).

EDIT: Justin and Eric's comments were spot-on - your main challenge is *getting in* to the country. I'm not sure what your plan is here, if you have neither credentials nor actual employment experience.

Comment: As the OP's goal is immigrating to places like the US, Canada and Europe, the major obstacle is not necessarily the company itself but rather the immigration requirements for those places.  Some basic experience in a field, even with a bachelor's degree, is not generally sufficient to cross the threshold to qualify for immigration.

Comment: @Eric - Ah ok, granted - that's the main issue then , a legal one

Comment: @Eric Immigration requirement does not (usually) distinguish between what your major is in school.  If you have a bachelor degree, 5 points, master degree, 8 points phD 10 points (just making these points up)... however, they do distinguish the industry you are in and whether your skills is something the country needs.

Comment: @Novina It sounds like you are describing Canada's system. Each country has a different system for determining immigration eligibility..

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a position can be positioned around your uniqueness, and not the actual responsibilities.  In many countries this will satisfy working requirements.

For instance, the position could be a liaison that is required to be a programmer, not a programmer that is required to be a liaison. If you were German I could not hire you on a green card if I couldn't defend that your qualifications are unique. As a liaison to our German team, I could easily defend that, and note your programming experience as a bonus that makes you difficult to find locally. The actual job tasks are the same.

A degree would just be a means of satisfying a requirement that you are skilled, not a requirement itself. You can prove programming skills through your open source projects, and your liaison skills with your degree.